# How to access the Flag completed date?

Tags: vba, outlook

I move my emails by selecting "Follow up - Mark completed Option", to another folder.
Now I want to write a program to check hom many emails did I complete today by comparing the Flag completed date with todays date.

But I am not able to find how to access the Flag completed date.

Can you please help.

Thanks,
Alok

Answer (score 4):

The property is Outlook.MailItem.TaskCompletedDate.  Try something like:

```
Sub GetCompletedToday()
Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim CompletedTodayCount As Long

Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.Folders(1).Folders("tester")

For Each olMailItem In olFolder.Items
    If olMailItem.TaskCompletedDate = Date Then
        CompletedTodayCount = CompletedTodayCount + 1
    End If
Next olMailItem
Debug.Print CompletedTodayCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the flags by using the `expression.FlagStatus`

See this link

**Topic: FlagStatus Property**

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212013%28v=office.11%29.aspx

For example, this will give you the status of all selected emails

**OUTLOOK VBA CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Messages As Selection
    Dim Msg As MailItem
    Dim NamSpace As NameSpace

    Set NamSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Messages = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If Messages.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    For Each Msg In Messages
        Debug.Print Msg.FlagStatus
    Next
End Sub
```

For message(s) with `No flags` it will give you a `0`

for `Mark Completed` it will give you `1` and

for `Other flags` it will give you `2`

So you can actually use an `If` statement to check for the `.FlagStatus` property and the Mail Date to achieve what you want.

HTH

Comment: Does the Mail Date reflect when the status was changed?

Comment: Doug, do you mean changing the flags changes the date as well? If yes, then, no, Flag Status doesn't alter the email date.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.  I asked because the OP wants to know which flags were changed to completed today, I think.  Does your answer show how to do that?

Comment: No his question is different. What I understood from his question is... He has moved emails "marked as complete" from folder A to Folder B. He wants to know at the end of the day how many "marked as complete" emails were moved for that particular date.